# Bind Asp.NET WebApi through port 21

Tags: asp.net-web-api

This may not be the correct place for this question as it's part networking, but here goes.

I am wanting to put together a WebApi (using the ASP.NET MVC WebApi framework) to be consumed by client machines external to our network. However the client machines resolve web traffic through a proxy server for which our software does not have authentication. We have noticed that outgoing FTP connections are possible though.

So I am wondering whether we can host the webapi and have client machines connect out through Port 21? Does that even make sense? Sorry if it's a stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find some answers and thought I would share for anyone that might be interested.

## Binding WebApi to ports other than 80

This is possible, but tricky. When you publish the Api project onto IIS (or wherever you are hosting it) you just bind it to an alternative port. You then also make sure you forward that port in your router. Then, clients of the API just specify the host using your custom port to access the endpoint through that port: `http://myhostname.com:21/api/values` or whatever.

### Complications

Testing the endpoints can be tricky as Chrome blocks HTTP traffic being sent via some ports - port 21 is one such port. So to test it you need to write a client exe that can hit the endpoints to make sure they are working (like a console application).

Despite figuring all of this out, I still could not connect out through the firewall. I suspect that some configuration is blocking the traffic because even though it is going out through an open port (21), it is **not** FTP traffic: it's HTTP traffic.

### A Solution

It occurred to me that SOAP operates through a range of protocols (FTP, SMTP, HTTP, to name a few) and formats its messages as XML. So in this scenario it would make more sense to use a SOAP service via Port 21 rather than REST which is *strictly* HTTP.